# Loop of all regressions with previous rows

Tags: r, loops, regression, phylogeny

I am trying to create a general linear regression model between a variable, and all variables before that, from two matrices, for every row.

I have two alike matrices with 30 rows and 41 columns, that both look like this:

```
            Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4 Subject5 Subject6 Subject7 Subject8 Subject9
Trial 1       NA       66       NA        6       NA       45       NA       NA       NA
Trial 2       10      105       10        6        6       NA        6       10       15
Trial 3       NA      136       10        6       10       45       15       10       NA
Trial 4       10       NA       10        6       10       45       28       NA        6
Trial 5       10       NA       15        6       15       45       36        0       10
Trial 6       NA       21       NA        6       15       45       55       10       10
```

Where one is NA the other one has a value.

I'm trying to loop a regression for every Trial, where the predicted Trial value (n-th) has all the previous values (n-1) as regressors.

After a lot of research I found a way for all possible regressions, with

```
expand.grid(c(TRUE,FALSE), c(TRUE,FALSE), c(TRUE,FALSE), c(TRUE,FALSE))
```

And building from that, but as the number of my regressors for the last model is 29 times 2 because of the 2 matrices it would create a way too huge grid, also I only need the model for previous Trials.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your response variable that you are trying to predict with regression?

Comment: Do the two matrices have different subjects, but same number of Trials?

Comment: Lloyd: the nem trial value. So trial 1, trial 2 predicts trial 3; trial 1:7 predicts trial 8, etc

Comment: useR: they have the same number of trials and subjects,  just to prevent one being negative i ordered them in different matrices. They are the values of the same test, but should be represented with different weight,  thus where one has a value,  other is NA

Comment: Lloyd: just to clarify more: so for trial 3 predictors would be trial 1, trial 2 from matrix 1. and trial 1 and trial 2 from matrix 2. Where one matrix has a value other matrix at exact same subject and trial has na, the values interjú the two matrices should be handled seperately